Graph neural networks in cybersecurity
I'm a mathematics undergraduate working on graph neural networks (GNNs). I read a piece online talking about GNNs being used in cybersecurity, but didn't dwell too much on the details. Could anyone recommend relevant resources, papers, articles, or courses that provide more detail on this topic?
- Thanks.

Always try Google Scholar: graph neural networks security.  Though, beware of the lax use of the term application.  That GNNs have applications in cybersecurity does not actually mean that someone is using GNNs in cybersecurity.

@JohnKemeny Alright, thank you for the reference and the heads up.

I will provide a few resources that could help. However, cybersecurity is not my field; GNNs are.
Research papers and articles:

Illuminati: Towards Explaining Graph Neural Networks for Cybersecurity Analysis (He et al., 2023)

VulEye: A Novel Graph Neural Network Vulnerability Detection Approach for PHP Application (Lin et al., 2023)

Graph Neural Networks for Intrusion Detection: A Survey (Bilot et al., 2024)

Use of Graph Neural Networks in Aiding Defensive Cyber Operations (Mitra et al., 2024)

Graph neural networks: a survey on the links between privacy and security (Guan et al., 2024)

GRAPHSEC – Advancing the Application of AI/ML to Network Security Through Graph Neural Networks (Casas et al., 2023)


Books and courses:

"Applied Graph Data Science: Graph Algorithms and Platforms, Knowledge Graphs, Neural Networks, and Applied Use Cases" (Raj et al., 2024). This books offers a few insights into graph data science, including GNNs and their applications in cybersecurity.

Platforms like Coursera and edX may also offer courses on GNNs, though not specifically in the context of cybersecurity. Nonetheless, it is worth checking out.


Hope this helps (:
